# Application doesn't work without android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-manifest

Well, when I run my app via android studio it works normally, if I install it from play market it doesn't work, but as soon as I launch android studio and it finds my emulator it starts working normally. I bet the problem is with my manifest.

P.S. Application is using GoogleMaps and MS Azure Simple App.

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My_APIKEY_is_actually_here:)" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What's the symptom when it doesn't work? Can you post a stack traceback and logcat info? What leads you to suspect the manifest?

Comment: @Jerry101 , main layout doesn't appear as a symptom. When app is working on debug and doesn't on release build I always suspect the manifest, since there is no point to suspect the code.

Comment: Many things are different between debug and release builds, e.g. release builds usually run ProGuard and that might've stripped out some needed code. Try running a release build within Android Studio, also try building one with gradlew, installing it into a device or emulator, and running that. Watch the logcat for error messages.

Comment: @Jerry101 ok, I'll try to

Comment: Make your release build debuggable by adding debuggable: true to "release" section in buildTypes. Then build your signed APK, install it manually to your device and look for the errors in Android Studio's Android Monitor window just like you do it during development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not added the SHA-1 fingerprint of your release key to your Google maps API key. Follow the instructions on getting your SHA-1 fingerprints here -- https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup. Check in the API console to make sure you've added your *release key* in addition to your debug key.